# How do I use a variable to specify the column name in C#.net (MVC)

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

lets say i got a variable that holds a whole row, i know its

```
row.column = "value";
```

and my code is :

```
public void editseatsnr(string seatPostion , int BusID)
    {
        var bus = db.Seats.Select( s => s.BusID).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

seatPostion is a string with the column name and BusID is a primary key in the first column

and heres a picture of the table :

[image: Picture of the table]

lets say i got "A2" in seatPostion , and bus is at second row, how to supposed to edit the cell ?

Comment: Row/Column of ADO.NET DataTable or something else? Are you trying to access a cell value by column name?

Comment: ^ We need to know what type of datatype you are using (ie. DataRow, DataTable, DataSet, etc.)

Comment: ya ado.net data table, and im using the MVC pattern, and yes im trying to change whats in a cell, but the user is who defines the column name.

Comment: What is the name of your `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 0):

if You Want To Set the `DatagridView` Column Name , You Can Use this Code :

```
 grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "First Column";
```

Also You Can Give The Name Of Column Instead Of index for example : `columns["name"]`

Comment: i got an error that says "the name 'grid' does not exist in the current context" ?

Comment: the error says that you should enter the correct name of column

Comment: well, lets say i got a table with the foloowing columns names : "BusID","A1","A2","A3","A4" hows my code supposed to be ?

Comment: grid.Columns["A1"].HeaderText = "Second Column";

Comment: I don't believe this question has anything to do with a `DatagridView` or `HeaderText`. Not sure why you're making that part of the answer.

Comment: I thought he means dataGridView Column Name!

Answer (score 0):

I `row` is of type `System.Data.DataRow`, then pulling the values from the row based on a variable that holds the name of the column would work like this:

```
row[myVariable] = "some value";
```

If you need to reference the values by a literal column name, then you would do something like this:

```
row["myColumn"] = "some value";
```

See the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MDSN article for more info.

Comment: Well, thats not working, i dont know if you people got my problem but i got this data table : http://prntscr.com/22lm1m , and my code is : public void editseatsnr(string seatPostion , int BusID)
        {
            var bus = db.Seats.Select( s => s.BusID).FirstOrDefault();
           
        } SeatPostion is the column name and the BusID is the primary key in the first column, lets say theres "A2" in the SeatPostion, how im supposed to edit the cell where row = 2 and column = A2 (if A2 is inside a variable )?

Comment: Sorry, update your original question with your sample code, so that it's properly formatted and we can help.